# python-opencv AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'createBackgroundSubtractorGMG'

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to follow the tutorial given in:
https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_video/py_bg_subtraction/py_bg_subtraction.html

While trying the third example (BackgroundSubtractorGMG) I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'createBackgroundSubtractorGMG'
```

I got the same error for the earlier examples. But I followed the explanation given in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18721552/opencv2-python-createbackgroundsubtractor-module-not-found). some how, the same trick did not work here.

If there is some one who has managed to solve it, please help me out.

Using Python 2.7.3 & opencv 2.4.6.1 on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: That tutorial is meant for OpenCV 3.x. So compile opencv from github master branch..

Comment: Thanks for the info I will use Open CV3 now!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

oh dear, that's another one of *those* stories ...

with 2.4.6, you only can use BackgroundSubtractorMOG from python. (full stop)

as of 2.4.8, it seems, the [BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 problem](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/commit/34a390fbc2b83638397066dbd89013da82f36003) got fixed, but the BackgroundSubtractorGMG is still missing.

with both versions, you use a plain constructor to create one.

in 3.0 (master), they changed the syntax, you now have to call 'createBackgroundSubtractorGMG', 'createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2' and such (that's what your tutorial might be refering to). but now you can use all 3 versions at least.

so in any way, if you want to use BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 , you'll have to update to 2.4.8, if you need BackgroundSubtractorGMG, you'll need 3.0 (which is 'bleeding edge' in a way, but the new interface has the far better control over the params needed, imho).

Comment: Actually, my 3.0.0-dev version (today's git master) does contain the `createBackgroundSubtractorMOG` and `createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2`, but not `createBackgroundSubtractorGMG` (on Python3). Still looking for that one.

Comment: Just in case someone is looking for this: I dove a bit deeper into why `createBackgroundSubtractorGMG` is missing, and posted a new question on it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29429863/why-is-createbackgroundsubtractorgmg-considered-obsolete-and-how-can-i-use-it

Answer (score 12):

In OpenCV 3.0.0-dev, you have to compile with the contrib repos and then it's in the bgsegm sub-module. I.e. just call cv2.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorGMG()

Comment: *Pokerfaced* Where they mention it? I couldn't see it in the docs, did I miss something? Great, another 20 minutes of recompiling.

Comment: I have 3.3 `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'bgsegm'`

Comment: @Maximilian Are you sure your version is compiled with opencv_contrib?

Comment: No! That is why! Thanks

Comment: This worked for me. Using 3.3.1 dev python-opencv

Answer (score 9):

```
cv2.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorGMG()
cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()
cv2.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG(),
```

**this worked for me **

Answer (score 2):

bgsegm was in contrib module of opencv, but after the update I am not sure.

But still,
if you have not built contrib module:

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

Make sure no console is running that has imported cv2 while you execute your installing process.
Run the `cmd` as Administration

It worked for me.