# Why is createBackgroundSubtractorGMG considered obsolete, and how can I use it

Tags: opencv, background-subtraction, opencv3.0

I am rather new to OpenCV and image processing in general. I am looking into background subtraction to facilitate motion tracking (people counting). Looking at [the openCV documentation on background subtracting](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_video/py_bg_subtraction/py_bg_subtraction.html#backgroundsubtractorgmg), GMG gives rather nice results. Also when looking at [a video comparing the methods](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-L9FoH3D9w), I feel that GMG gives the best results, at least for my purpose.

I installed the latest version of opencv to use with python3 thus:

```
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git
cd opencv
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DBUILD_opencv_python3=YES -DBUILD_opencv_python2=NO -DINSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=YES -DPYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/python3 -DPYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/include/python3.4m -DPYTHON3_LIBRARY=/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/libpython3.4.dylib -DPYTHON3_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS=/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include/ -DPYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ ..
make -j8
make install
python3 -c "import cv2; print(cv2.__version__)"
```

the last line tells me I'm now running `3.0.0-dev`. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21626619/python-opencv-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-createbackground), `cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorGMG` ought to be available in this version, however it's not; and indeed, it seems to [have been moved to obsolete](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/pull/3626) in opencv master.

Interestingly enough, in my own tests the current (3.0.0-dev) versions of `createBackgroundSubtractorKNN` and `createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2` work much better than the ones I tested before (`MOG` and `MOG2`) in opencv2. So possibly the `GMG` algorithm got moved into those. Or, if not, why is the `GMG` version considered obsolete now? And how can I get the obsolete version to work (on python3), to compare the results?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is obsolete... it was just moved to the [`contrib`](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib) repository. You have to install it with OpenCV and then it is available under `cv2.bgsegm`. Follow the link for build instructions.

Comment: Somebody should specify this into the tutorials on their documentation, as they are not reproducible. https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/db/d5c/tutorial_py_bg_subtraction.html