# How to subtract the background from an image - python , opencv

Tags: python, image, opencv, background-subtraction

How to subtract the background in a still image? IF the issue is with videos then we can use `cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG()`. I tried to manipulate the function, but I got `AttributeError`

This is what i have tried:

```
img = cv2.imread('lena.png')
fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()
fgmask = fgbg.apply(img)
cv2.imwrite('{0:d}.jpg'.format(i),fgmask)
```

But I got this error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2'
```

Any suggestion are welcome!

Comment: @Numbers I have added what I have tried. I don'tt know whether I'm right or not.

Comment: [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18721552/opencv2-python-createbackgroundsubtractor-module-not-found)

Comment: @Constantine Its for the video I guess, but not for the still image. I want the background subtraction for still image.

Comment: You could hack and "train" the MOG2 with your stil image and insert the other one as a foreground.

Comment: @user3483746 If you only give the algorithm a single image, it cannot know what is foreground and what is background unless you somehow tell him ...

Comment: Have you tried Core.absdiff(bkgrndImage, image, destImg)?

Comment: What version of OpenCV are you using? I think this function is only available in 3.0.0-dev

Comment: @medloh is this function available in opencv 2.4.6?? `Core.absdiff()`?

Comment: I'm only familiar with the Java bindings.  I know it was there in 2.4.7, and 99% sure it was in 2.4.6.  Not sure what the comparable call in Python would be.

Comment: Replace `createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2` with `BackgroundSubtractorMOG`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenCV2 Python createBackgroundSubtractor module not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18721552/opencv2-python-createbackgroundsubtractor-module-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

```
fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()
```

is not available in opencv3 tutorial - instead you can use:

```
fgbg = cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG2()
```